# Script to copy formulas when inserting row at the top - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a call log that has multiple drop-downs and formulas for making the data entry easier for the people using it. The problem is that when I insert a row (in row 2 under header) the data validation remains but the formulas don't copy. I have tried several scripts but none of them seem to work. I have about 10 columns with formulas in them.

Comment: use arrayformula

Comment: share a copy of your sheet or formula

Comment: Please add screenshots or video. It's very hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Welcome. Ironically, you have the same problem as if you added a row at the bottom of the sheet - have you considered perhaps copying the formula cells from another line, or building the formula (`setformula`) in your script?

Comment: This is a link to the sample file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S73GR7kqeogg2L1z0z-jY5c6-qhcvSEl7vNzAYBNmGQ/edit?usp=sharing I have formulas in Column B and Columns Z through AK that I need to "copy up" when I insert a new row at the top in row 2 (under the header)

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question and studying your example, I assume the following:

- You want to add a new row after the headers.
- You desire to keep the formulas and data validation rules in the old rows.
- You wish to copy the formulas of the old rows into the new one.

If my assumptions are correct, you can use the following example to fulfill your requests:

#### CODE

```js
function addRowAtTop() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
    '{SPREADSHEET ID}').getSheetByName(
    'PNC Calls');

  sheet.insertRowAfter(1);

  for (var i = 1; i <= 34; i++) {
    var cellFormula = sheet.getRange(3, i).getFormula();
    if (cellFormula != '') {
      sheet.getRange(2, i).setFormula(cellFormula);
    }
  }
}
```

#### BEHAVIOUR

The previous code will add a row at the top, and after that it will check each cell of the old first row. If it encounters a formula, it will copy it to the new first row.

#### ALLUSIONS

- [`getFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)

Please take this as one of the possible solutions to your issue, and don't hesitate to write me back with any additional doubts or requests to further clarifications.